# Multi Thread Java in case of static array - one thread is updating and another thread is reading array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets, static

There is array Link ports[4] which is defined as static and part of main thread. In my project, there are various producer and consumer threads which are using this array by using static reference i.e. using name of class to access array. In some part of project, his array is getting update and other part of project this array is being read. How should I use synchronized, wait , notify or join so as I can maintain consistency in my code?

```
class Router{  \\ on main thread
static  Link[] ports = new Link[4];

 void processCnnect {
 else if(Router.ports[i]==null && processPort > 1023 && processPort<=65535)
          {
   Router.ports[i] =new Link(rd,rd_c); 
        }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread
{
                           // reading then updating Router.ports[]
}
There are some threads which perform heart beat mechanism by sending packets to other consumer (receiver) like alive messages. Its a mix of multi threading and  socket programming.
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @syam.k I have shared code snippet. I cant share the entire code since it has academic integrity associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the server thread is the one which writes into ports, and the worker threads service the individual ports. In that case, you can have a read-write lock.

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

server thread:

```
class ServerThread extends Thread
{
  readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
  // read ports here
  readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
  // if these ports need to be updated, acquire the write lock
  readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
  // only one writer can enter this section,
  // and only if no threads are currently reading.
  readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

worker threads:

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread
{
  readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
  // read ports here, and service them
  readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is a good option, you may also consider implementing of `Optimistic Read` through `StampedLock`. When the number of *readers* is significantly greater than the numbers of *writers*, `Optimistic Read` outperforms the others. Moreover, in a practical scenario, both read and write operations rarely happen at the same time. Therefore, optimistic read works most of the time.

```
private final StampedLock stLock = new StampedLock();
```

**Reader**

```
long stamp = stLock.tryOptimisticRead();

// read ports here!

if (stLock.validate(stamp) == false) {  
     // optimistic reading fails (write occurred) - read again through read-lock.
     stamp = stLock.readLock();
     try {
          // read ports here!
     } finally {
          stLock.unlockRead(stamp);
     }                
}
```

**Writer**

```
long stamp = stLock.writeLock();
try {
     // write ports here!
} finally {
     stLock.unlockWrite(stamp);
}
```

> How should I use synchronized, wait , notify or join so as I can maintain consistency in my code?

`synchronized` - You can maintain consistency through `synchronized`, but it is not a good choice here. If a code segment or method is `synchronized` only one thread can execute that block or method at one time. In a typical read/write scenario, it is not efficient because multiple read operations are not mutually exclusive.

`wait()/notify()` - If your concern is just getting the most up-to-date value then there is nothing to do with `wait()/notify()`. They are designed to block (release) a thread until (when) a specific condition is met.

`join()` - allows one thread to wait until another thread completes its execution.